# Latex tag for making a comment appear or disappear in pdf?

Tags: latex

Is it possible to tag sections of your .tex file so that you can make text appear or not?

I have a long document and would like to be able to comment a certain section in each chapter, and produce two different pdfs, one with the comments, and one without.

I read [here](http://devdaily.com/blog/post/latex/multi-line-comments-in-latex-begin-123-comment-125-verbatim) about the `\begin{comment}` tag in the `verbatim` package. Is it possible to make this appear if I redefined the comment tag? How is this done?

Thank you.

---

On suggestion, included the question to tex.stackexchange.com [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/latex-tag-for-making-a-comment-appear-or-disappear-in-pdf), however there is not much traffic on that site.

Comment: Probably better to ask on http://latex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does that site exist? The link didn't work

Comment: @celenius, it's http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok - I'll ask it there. Thanks

Comment: Note that latex question remain on-topic here. You are just likely to get help *faster* on [TeX, LaTeX and Friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I did get an answer there, that solved my problem. Should I link to it here? or just delete this question?

Comment: You could provide the accepted answer here as well. That way, other users don't need to navigate away to another page to find the answer. Chances are, most people with the same problem won't read all the comments, maybe not even call up the question, when no answer has been given... an accepted answer on the other hand, makes your question more interesting to read for someone in search of the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph
on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3023/latex-tag-for-making-a-comment-appear-or-disappear-in-pdf)

> Yes, this is indeed possible, and it’s
>   very simple, too: just redefine the
>   comment environment as follows:
>
> ```
> \renewenvironment{comment}{}{}
> ```
>
> This will cause the comment text to be
>   included as normal text.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the **pdfcomment** package, which is working out very nicely:
http://pdfcomment.berlios.de/

allows one to add sticky-note type comments throughout the resulting pdf file.

simply set a global option for pdfcomment in your preable to either 'draft' or 'final' to make the comments show up or not.

I'm finding this extremely helpful for reminding myself where i need to add a reference/figure etc.  However, I'm using Mac OS & pdftex (default for TexLive 2009), which has excellent support for PDF comments (in both Safari & Preview.app).  Not really sure how well supported this is on Linux/Windows type OS's.

Example preamble:

`\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\pdfcommentsetup{draft} % set to 'final' to prevent all comments from showing up
\pdfcommentsetup{color={1.0 1.0 0.0}, open=true}`

Example usage:

`... diffuse into the substrate in every direction - ie. radially.\pdfcomment{Need reference for this type of model.} ...`